# Can 'go build' and 'go test' have default tags?

Tags: go

Specifically, I'm using the magick package, and the features I'm using dictate that I always need to build it with the 'gm' build tag. Is there a way to declare that build tag by default, so that 'go build' for my project (or 'go test') will implicitly build magick using 'gm'?

Comment: Are you sure everybody knows "package magick"? Btw: Makefile

Comment: It's just an example of a package that needs a build tag. Yes, I can use a makefile if I have to. I was wondering if that could be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they can't. You either have to type them on the cmd line or use a makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `!gm` as default tag?

```
// +build gm
```

```
// +build !gm
```